# compare file txt powershell ad output to a object

Tags: powershell

i have two txt files with some folder permissions:

**file "old"**

```
pc1 test  everyone full control
pc2 test everyone full control
```

**file new**

```
pc1 test  everyone full control
pc3 test  everyone full control
pc2 test  everyone full control
```

How I can use the `Compare-Object` command to find the differences in the two files and write it in a PowerShell object?

Comment: it is very difficult to understand what you want to do , modifiy the question with an example and be more clear!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PowerShell function that should accomplish what you are looking for.  As @Frank  mentioned, you should provide some more details and a concrete example so we can be sure the solution suggested answers your question. I'm making some pretty big assumptions about the format of your text file.

Take the function below, and save it as a .ps1 file and include it like such:

```
. c:\temp\Get-Permission.ps1
```

Then, call the Get-Permission function as shown in the examples:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Permission -File C:\temp\old.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Permission -File C:\temp\new.txt)
```

That should do it.  Here is the function:

```
function Get-Permission()
{
  <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    This function reads a set of permissions defined in a text file.  

    .DESCRIPTION 
    The text file is space-delimited but for the last field.  The format is as follows:
      Machine Name    - Specifies the name of the machine the file is on.
      File Name       - Specifies the name of the folder the permission applies to.
      Principal       - Specifies the principal the permission is applied against.
      Permission      - Specifies the permission on the file.

    Example:
      pc1 test  everyone full control
      pc3 test  everyone full control
      pc2 test  everyone full control

    .PARAMETER File
    Specifies the file to read the permissions from.

    .INPUTS 
    [System.Io.FileInfo]

    .OUTPUTS
    [PSCustomObject[]]
    A PSCUstomObject with the following properties:
      ComputerName
      File
      Principal
      Permission

    .EXAMPLE
    #  Get the permissions structure from the old file:
    Get-Permission -File c:\temp\old.txt

    Permission   ComputerName File Principal
    ----------   ------------ ---- ---------
    full control pc1          test everyone
    full control pc3          test everyone

    .EXAMPLE  
    #  Get the permissions structure from the old and new files and compare:
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Permission -File C:\temp\old.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Permission -File C:\temp\new.txt)

    InputObject                                                                 SideIndicator
    -----------                                                                 -------------
    @{Permission=full control; ComputerName=pc2; File=test; Principal=everyone} =>
  #>
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
    [string] $File
  )

  process
  {
    foreach ( $ln in (Get-Content -Path $File) )
    {
      $split = $ln -split " +"
      New-Object -TypeName "PSCustomObject" -Property `
      @{
        "ComputerName"    = $split[0]
        "File"            = $split[1]
        "Principal"       = $split[2]
        "Permission"      = ($split | Select-Object -Skip 3) -join " "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Oldfile -DifferenceObject $Newfile|Out-File differenze.txt

Comment: process
  {
    foreach ( $ln in (Get-Content -Path differenze.txt) )
    {
      $split = $ln -split " +"
      New-Object -TypeName "PSCustomObject" -Property `
      @{
        "ComputerName"    = $split[0]
        "File"            = $split[1]
        "Principal"       = $split[2]
        "Permission"      = ($split | Select-Object -Skip 3) -join " "
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: the script is ok, but what i can do to skip the first 3 lines of the file? tnx

Comment: I"m still not sure what you are doing.  Did you see the examples I provided in the function above?  You'd use it like this:  `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Permission -File C:\temp\old.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Permission -File C:\temp\new.txt)`

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the output from there?  Write it to a file?  Read it back?  If you write it to a file, you would probably do it this way:  `Compare-Object $oldFile $newfile | Select -ExpandProperty inputobject | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\difference.txt'